# How to continuously monitor a table in a mysql database and triger a php script to work on it?

Tags: php, mysql, monitoring

What I want to do is to monitor a table in mysql which is always auto-updated by a sms gateway.

The script should be monitored continuously and as soon as there is a new entry in the table, a php script ritn to perform further operations should be triggered.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: does the timing of the update to php start need to be instant? if not a cron job checking every minute may be sufficient

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, but look up Ajax with long polling, and Comet.

Comment: I reckon you shouuld refine your search to CRON-JOB!

Comment: Where / what is the code that receives messages from the SMS gateway and uses them to update the table? Could you have that script call the desired PHP script whenever it makes an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done exactly this lots of times using cron. So your php script starts by seeing if there is a new entry, and then does what it needs to do if there is. If there's nothing to work on, it just exits immediately. One thing to bear in mind is that if the script takes a long time to run, you want to make sure your cron jobs are set accordingly, so they don't overlap.

One simple way to achieve this is to have a special column in the table which indicates whether the row has been examined by the php script or not. So when the php script runs, it looks for all data that has that field false. Something like this:

```
SELECT id from my_table where dealt_with = FALSE;
```

And then when it's run on those rows, it updates them:

```
UPDATE my_table set dealt_with = TRUE where id=1234;
```

Comment: That's a lot of MySQL updates there, actually, you will update every record once, that's pretty heavy for a high-load projects. If you run CRON on some timed interval like one minute, wouldn't it be better if at the time of insertion you would insert an additional field `time_created` and then simply `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE NOW() - time_created < 60` ?

Comment: @Vlakarados: you're probably right, but that approach feels a little more brittle to me: i.e., if it gets half way through a batch and then dies, what happens when it restarts?

Comment: Yes, that's something you should bother about if your hosting is not reliable and if updating is really mandatory. I'm not saying your approach is bad, I just suggest. You can always have a CRON job fire another script that keeps the last row id that it has dealt with, for example in some txt file or what would be much better - memcache. It really depends on what are the requirements to the application, but if the author says he want's to check for new rows every 1-2 seconds I can suggest this project will be pretty high-load.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding an AFTER UPDATE [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) to your table.
Each time a record is updated, your trigger code will be automatically executed.

The code in the trigger is a list of MySQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Jocelyn suggested a pretty good solution for a project with documentation, otherwise it is a killer for other developers that might want to change anything as it is something that is always overlooked.

The limitation with MySQL `AFTER UPDATE` is that it can only run SQL, not a PHP script. So the best solution would be to run a [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job every * minutes that launches a PHP script, which checks for the last value of the auto-increment field such as an `id` field, for example with mysql_insert_id. The reason behind using this logic is because you would not want to check for the number of rows as some of them might have been deleted.

Comment: BUt i need the php script to be exicuted immideately! can i set the minutes to 0.1 or something so that it becomes check/sec or check/2sec?

Comment: Of course, read about CRON, it's easy to use and there are dozens of tutorials

Comment: I realize this is old, but for people like me that stumble on this, this might help.  My proposal would be a hybrid.  Use the after update trigger to populate a temporary table that will hold the keys of the rows recently inserted.  In your PHP script run by CRON, have it check the temporary table for IDs of the primary table that need need to be scripted.  Once yourun your PHP script, truncate the temporary table.  This way you are not constantly accessing the primary table.  Only when there are records to process.